Should I put 0 with decimal points (e.g., 0.00) in a figure for visual consistency?
I have a question about the visual consistency on the figure axes. Let's say I have a figure and on its x axis the following values are displayed:
-0.50 -0.40 -0.30 -0.20 -0.10 0 0.10 0.20 0.30 0.40 0.50

Is it better to have 0 written as 0.00 here for visual consistency? Or is it redundant or even wrong to do so?

where is the figure going? many organizations/publications have style guides.

It seems like the trailing zero in all of the other points is more redundant than 0.0 or 0.00 would be, but it might be defensible if you have a number that is usually expressed in a 2-decimal format.

@RichardErickson, the figure is not going anywhere :) , I was just curious whether there was a correct and preferred way to do it.

I would include the number of significant figures in the label, be internally consistent within your document, and match any style guides (for example, a university of a thesis or dissertation or a journal's style guide for an article).

Well-spaced tick marks on a figure axis are (presumed to be) infinitely precise and perfectly accurate in their value. The digit limits you choose to use to display the number at each tick is a matter of the convention defined by the receiving audience, by the conventions required to convey the exact accurate value at each tick, and by your conventions for aesthetics in reading the figure.
Be cautious in cases where computer programs make seeming semi-intelligent choices for the number of ticks you might want on an axis as their first priority rather than choosing well-defined tick increments. Such a choice often leads to tick values marked at irrational number settings. Because irrational numbers require an infinite number of digits to report with perfect accuracy, they are certainly to be avoided as tick values on a figure.

If the zero results from a measurement and has two decimal point accuracy then yes, it should be written as 0.00. If it is precisely zero then things seem inconsistent in your measuring system. So, is 0.000001 a possible value, though beyond the capabilities of your system, or are the other values like 0.10 merely nominal, rather than approximate measurements?
Consistency is good in any case.

0.00 does not imply an experimental measurement, the values are the values displayed on the x axis, I guess the ticks are the correct word for them?
